# Best way to implement audio playback on iPad

Tags: iphone

Should I used AVPlayer or MovieController?

I have tried using AVPlayer but I cannot reference it even though I added AVFoundation as a framework to my target.

EDIT: I have added the AVFoundation.framework to my 'frameworks' folder.  Then at the top of my header file I am trying to reference the correct framework so that I can use AVPlayer

Comment: please add what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVPlayer is what you need.
Did you import AVFoundation in your file?

```
   #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```